# Static method call from AsyncTask is async?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to use a `AsyncTask` to check if internet connection is available and then doing some stuff.

My problem is while the comprobation is being executed I can´t interacting with the `UI`. The "`progressbar`" is on front and if I try to click on a button the `UI` doesn't respond

This is the call to AsyncTask

```
@Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
            AsyncHttpHandler check = new AsyncHttpHandler(**paramaters**);
            check.execute("checkshared"); 

    }
```

This is the code of AsyncTask

```
public class AsyncHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


    public AsyncHttpHandler(Context c, Intent i, Bundle _data, String _language){
        ctx = c;
        intent = i;
        data = _data;
        language = _language;

        startClock();


    }

    public void startClock(){
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx,R.style.MyTheme);                  
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mDialog.show();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... peticion) {
        String response = "null";
        //call to check if internet connection is available
        if(Utils.isInternetConn(ctx)){

        try {

            // do stuff
            response = "...";

        }
        else response = "offline";

        return response;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(mDialog != null) mDialog.dismiss();

        if(!response.equals("offline")){
        // do stuff
        }
        else Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(language+"_toast_nointernet", "string", ctx.getPackageName())), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

And this is the method to check if the internet connection is available:

```
public static Boolean isInternetConn(Context ctx){

    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    boolean conectado = false;
    if((wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting())){   

        try {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();             
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            URL myurl = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            URLConnection connection;
            connection = myurl.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            int responseCode = -1;
            responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                  conectado = true;
                  httpConnection.disconnect();
            }
            else {
                httpConnection.disconnect();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
    }

  return conectado;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us how you execute your task ?

Comment: What ever you do in asynch tasks doInBackground method runs in asynch way.Does progress bar disappears on your touch ? or it is staying in rotation even if you touched outside the progress bar ? Try  mDialog.setCancelable(true);

Comment: @Gordak I've added the call to AsyncTask to the original question.

Comment: @pcj You´re right, this is the problem

Comment: Not related to the question, bu anyway, you should set `conectado=false` inside the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your AsyncTask calling static method. That will also execute async. Problem is that you are showing progress dialog until your task finishes. And, of course, while your progress dialog is visible you will not be able to interact with the UI. If you want to interact with the UI, show your progress in another way, not with dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You display a progressDialog on top of the screen. The progress dialog takes the UI interaction, so the buttons underneath don't respond. If you use a progress bar in your UI instead of a progress dialog, your buttons will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **show the progress** of your task to the user, use the method [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)), as it has been implemented to run on the UI thread.

Now, each time you want to show the progress from doInBackground, call it by passing an argument. To be clear, **AsyncTask (String, Integer, String)** uses argument types:

- First is the type of argument you pass when you call execute
- Second is the type of the argument you pass to onProgressUpdate
- Third is the type of argument you pass to onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood what is your problem, but it seems to me, that you cannot interact with UI because the ProgressDialog is not cancelable, and it's in front of everything else.
You will only have feedback when dialog is dismissed.